# Customize the Watch debug window of VS2010 so I don't have to drill down

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, ozcode

Is it possible to make it so I don't have to drill all the way down in my Powershell "results" object to see the Name, Typename, and Value of the collection shown below??

Ideally I'd like to override the `ToString()` method of the `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mapi.MailboxStatistics` object.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/), it allows you to "star" variables within structures and they then appear in the main list.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you just enter `results[0].Properties[0]` into the watch window where you entered `results`?

Comment: I just right clicked on the variable to add to a watch.  How do I do what you're talking about?

Comment: (part 2) Ideally I'd like to see all the members of this IEnumerable in an eye-pleasing way.  I'd love to override the ToString method of this object, but I'm not even sure how to tell if this collection member is sealed or not.

Comment: Just type the expression into the watch window. If your expression is an IEnumerable, one of the things available to you will be "results view".

Answer (score 1):

I use **Watch Window** of Visual Studio for this. Once the variable name is stored there, you can re-evaluate its value during the debug session.

If you would like to override a `ToString()` method then you will need to create your own wrapper-class which will have the formatted `ToString()`. You would also need to use your class wrapper instead (I am not sure if it is possible, it may not be when `MailboxStatistics` is used somewhere internally).

Alternatively, you can use logging and output the result to whatever location you need, such as text file, Output Window of VS or elsewhere. See log4net or NLog for that (these seems to be the most popular open-source logging libs)